# How to handle large filter options

Tags: website-design, user-research

I'm working on a gaming website project where users go through large amounts of data and search results. on a search page users can filter through historical platforms.
The problem is that there are over 120 platforms and the vast majority of them are 'legacy' and could be irrelevant to the majority of users.

Is hiding all the legacy options considered bad practice? And if not what could be a good approach, maybe behind a search box?

Thanks!

[image: search filters]

[image: game platform dropdown]

Answer (score 1):

If you can't control who is using the search bar, you can't be sure if the user will be needing the particular "legacy" result or not, therefore you can't be cherrypicking what results you show or not.

There is a level of freedom on the level of order. You could let's say have two groups of results in the same list. Both groups ordered alphabetically one after the other. The first group is the one that has the items that are searched the most and the second one has the legacy (less searched items) underneath. [image]

Hope this helps.